# Blender 3 Material Application Problem

Tags: mesh, materials

I have the Blender 3 Release Candidate installed.

What I am trying to do is add a material to selected mesh on a UV Sphere and for some reason it refuses to add the material ONLY to the mesh I have selected. Instead it adds the material to the entire mesh.

Here are the steps I follow:

Sphere already added and positioned with a mirror modifier applied (eyeballs).

Edit mode, face mode & Viewport Shading.

In Edit mode the whole mesh is selected. No materials exist yet.

I use the Circle selector to deselect the iris and pupil (CTRL-select).

With a Shader Editor window at the bottom of the screen I click New (Material).

I click Assign. Then Deselect and then Select (in the properties panel).

The Select shows the whole mesh as being assigned.

This is obviously broken, no?

Comment: once you've created a material slot for your object, the material will be assigned to the whole object. If you want some other parts to have another material, create a new slot, give it a new material, and assign this material to this part

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as offtopic because it is about unfinished experimental under development versions of the software.